# Laravel 5 FormRequest custom message for array file field

Tags: validation, laravel-5

How can we set custom message for form array fields? Let me explaining by showing you some of my code.

```
Form Field:
{!! Form::file('doc[]', array('multiple'=>true)) !!}

FormRequest:
public function validator($factory)
    {
        $v = $factory->make($this->all(), $this->rules());
        $v->each('doc', ['required','mimes:doc,docx,jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048']);
        return $v;
    }
```

**by Default it shows:**

- The doc.1 must be a file of type: doc, docx, jpg, jpeg, png.
- The doc.2 must be a file of type: doc, docx, jpg, jpeg, png.

**but I want show**

- The {filename} must be a file of type: doc, docx, jpg, jpeg, png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to set custom messages for form array fields.

```
public function validator($factory)
    {
        $messages = [
            'doc.0.required' => "You must provide at least one document.",
        ];

        if(Request::hasFile('doc')) {
            $docs = Request::file('doc');
            foreach ($docs as $key => $val) {
                $messages['doc.' . $key . '.mimes'] = 'The document ' . $val->getClientOriginalName() . ' must be a file of type: :values.';
                $messages['doc.' . $key . '.max'] = 'The document ' . $val->getClientOriginalName() . ' may not be greater than :max kilobytes.';
            }
        }

        $v = $factory->make($this->all(), $this->rules(),$messages);
        $v->each('doc', ['required','mimes:pdf,doc,docx,jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048']);
        return $v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. One way is to overwrite the language file in your validation.php or follow any other approach defined in http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-error-messages

In validation.php you will find

```
"mimes"                => "The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.",
```

change it to

```
"mimes"                => "The documents must be a file of type: :values.",
```

If you want to have file name in the message then do something like this

```
$messages = [
  'mimes' => "The $fileName must be a file of type: :values.",
];    
$v = $factory->make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Comment: I already tried these things but no get success, can you tell me exactly some code which i use to change validation message

Comment: Edited answer for you.

Comment: what if i want to show a file name instead of documents?

Comment: I hope this edit is now good enough for accepting the answer :)

Comment: yeah u r right. but where is this **$fileName** coming from?

Comment: You can get the uploaded file as $request->file. This needs deeper investigation of your code of what and how have you implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $file = $request->file('user_detail');
    $credentials =[
        'file'      => $file,
        'extension' => strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
    ];

    $rules = [
        'file'          => 'required',
        'extension'      => 'required|in:xlsx',
    ];
    $msg = [
        'file.required' => "file is required.",
        'extension.in' => "only accept .xlsx file.",

    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($credentials,$rules,$msg);
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return $validator->messages()->all();
    }
```